# Firebase JWT AUTH with JaggeryJS Server Side Javascript (Not Node.js)

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, jaggery-js

I am trying to create a JWT for Firebase authentication using the server side javascript language: jaggeryJS.

Below I will outline

1. My approach to the JWT creation
2. The front-end response.

## 1 My approach to the JWT creation

HmacSHA256 function comes from Google's CryptoJS library and the Base64.encode is as outlined [here][3] but adding a second parameter to allow for websafe escaping.

```
<%
//create a jwt

//==============================================
//INCLUDES
    include('../lib/config.js');
    include('../lib/crypto/hmac-sha256.js');
    include('../lib/crypto/base64.js');

//==============================================
// HEADER
var header = {
    "alg": "HS256",
    "typ": "JWT"
}


//==============================================
// CLAIMS
var claims = {
    "v": 0,
    "iat": Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
    "d": {"user":"test"},
    "exp": (60 * 60 * 24 * 60),
    "admin": true,
    "debug": true
}


//PREPARE SIGNING
    var headerBase64  =  Base64.encode(stringify(header), true),
        claimBase64   =  Base64.encode(stringify(claims), true),
        signingInput  = headerBase64 + "." + claimBase64;



//CREATE SIGNATURE
    var hash      = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signingInput, FIREBASECONFIG.secret).toString(),
        signature = Base64.encode(hash, true);


//CONSTRUCT JWT ('jot') TOKEN
    var jwtToken = signingInput + "." + signature;


print(jwtToken);
```

## 2 The front-end response.

> var dataRef = new
>   Firebase("https://intense-heat-2343.firebaseio.com");
>
> var AUTH_TOKEN = "...." //what is printed above "jwtToken"
>
> dataRef.auth(AUTH_TOKEN, function(error) {   if(error) {
>       console.log("Login Failed!", error);   } else {
>       console.log("Login Succeeded!");   } });

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

> Login Failed! Error {code: "INVALID_TOKEN", stack: (...), message:
>   "INVALID_TOKEN: Could not parse auth token."}

When I pass my secret in directly I am able to authenticate successfully. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Here's a utility you can use for creating and reading tokens which may help with troubleshooting: http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/embedded/result/. Also, as of the latest version of Firebase, all tokens must include a `uid` in the data payload. (none of these answer your question, but hopefully will help)

Comment: Another thought would be to try applying some of the validation from one of the open source [token generators](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/simple-login/custom.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries), like [this one](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-node/blob/master/js/src/validation.js).